# Visual Studio Integrated shell example

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-shell

It seems there is very limited documentation on creating a Visual Studio Integrated shell application. I am looking for any pointers both for documentation and an example of creating such app.